# OCMock returns method not invoked but I am sure it was

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocmock

I am new to OCMock and I am having some issues. I have already read the official documentation, but coun't find how to solve my issue. I need to verify a method on a `sharedInstance` is called, and I am trying to do it this way:

```
-(void)setUp {
    ...
    _mockManager = OCMClassMock([CSBManager class]);
    OCMStub([_mockManager sharedInstance]).andReturn(_mockManager);
    [_logger setManager:_mockManager];
}
```

and then

```
-(void) someTest {
    //arrange

    //act

    OCMVerify([_mockManager doSomethingWithData:[OCMArg isKindOfClass:[NSData class]] fromString:[OCMArg isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] success:[OCMArg any] failure:[OCMArg any]]);
}
```

Logger code calling the method I am trying to verify is as follows:

```
[self.manager doSomethingWithData:self.someData 
               fromString:self.someString 
                  success:^(NSDictionary *mapping) {

                         //success code goes here

                } failure:^(NSError *error) {

                         //failure code goes here                                                                     

}];
```

I am sure that the method is being called, but the test does not pass due to error 
`Method doSomethingWithData:<OCMBlockConstraint: 0x7ff252a65a10> fromString:<OCMBlockConstraint: 0x7ff252a5f170> success:<OCMAnyConstraint: 0x7ff252a38350> failure:<OCMAnyConstraint: 0x7ff252a5f200> was not invoked.`

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The method that your manager instance is calling is named `doSomething`, while you're trying to verify that `doSomethingWithData` was invoked. Is that a mistake?

Comment: @Artal Not really, I was just trying to anonymize my code in order to post the question, but production code is right so unfortunately, that's not the reason

Comment: yes, i've noticed that these are not real method names :) I just wanted to make sure that you are verifying the correct method, because it was unclear

Comment: @Artal And that could perfectly be the reason of my problem, so thank you so much anyway!